# Inserting Array References into Perl Heap

Tags: perl, arrays, insert, reference

I am inserting 2-dimensional array references into my heap in Perl. 
How should I define the 'elements' attribute when constructing my heap so that I can properly use my comparator function?

```
my $heap = Heap::Simple->new( order     => \&byNumOrStr,
                              elements  => [Array => 0]
                             );

sub byNumOrStr
{
    my ( $a, $b ) = @_;

    $b->[0] <=> $a->[0]  #0-th element is a number. 
            ||
    $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]; #1-st element is a number
}
```

I keep getting back this error:

Can't use string ("2.55") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use ... (This means I might actually have to compare my "number string" numerically)

Comment: Part 1 (for context): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146484/secondary-order-in-heapsimple/3146526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's likely that either `$a` or `$b` is being passed in as a string. Try printing out this variables after the assignment.

From what I can see from the documentation, when you pass `elements => [ Array => 0 ]`, unless the 0th item in the array is an array then you'll only be comparing the *values* in the first slot of the array.

> `[Array => $index]`
>
> Indicates that the elements are array references, with the key at index $index. So now the element can be not just the key, but also associated data.

This means that if 2.55 is in the array like [ 2.55, ... ] then that's what's being passed in as `$a` or `$b`.

The `elements` entry tells `H::S` how you want to derive the key. For a completely generic way, it says that you can pass `[Function => $code_ref_for_key]`. You could make it like this:

sub first_two_slots { 
      my $array_ref = shift;
      return [ @$array_ref[0,1] ];
  }

And then with the order as specified, it would pass that array into your order and specify

```
my $heap = Heap::Simple->new( order     => \&byNumOrStr,
                              elements  => [Function => \&first_two_slots]
                             );
```

---

**Original comment left in place:** (It's not relevant to how `Heap::Simple` calls order).

if `byNumOrStr` is called from `sort` *DON'T* assign `$a` and `$b` in it. Those values are set by `sort`. If there is something coming in `@_` it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Those are different variables anyway, since sort's $a and $b are package veriables

Comment: @Leon Timmermans, I don't think it matters. If he lexicalizes `$a` and `$b` then those are the ones it's going to try to reference as arrays, not the ones in the symbol table.

Comment: I don't think `$a` and `$b` can be lexicalized. `perldoc perlvar` says: "Special package variables when using sort(), see "sort" in perlfunc.  Because of this specialness $a and $b don't need to be declared (using use vars, or our()) even when using the "strict 'vars'" pragma.  Don't lexicalize them with "my $a" or "my $b" if you want to be able to use them in the sort() comparison block or function."

Comment: You can lexicalize `$a` and `$b` but afterward, when sort tries to localize them it is going to blow up with `Can't use "my $a" in sort comparison.` You can use `$::a` and `$::b` to get around it, but best not to lexicalize them in the first place

Comment: When passing the function to the elements entry, are we creating new array references to be inserted into the Heap? I am inserting many, many of these references into my Heap and I'm noticing a 700% increase in runtime. Can I do anything to optimize it? Creating new question in a couple of mins....

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a two-dimensional array doesn't really make sense -- when you sort something, there is a defined order.  Having two sort criteria doesn't make it a two-dimensional list...  do you mean that you have data that are a list of two elements?  e.g.:

```
my $element = [ '0', 'string' ];
```

<strike>I think Example 1 in the documentation ("where key and value are kept separate") applies here -- you want to sort the references, not the values themselves.  So try declaring with `elements => "Any"`, and then adjust your sort method to match:</strike>

(I was wrong.. it looks like `elements => [Array => 0]` is correct, since these are just plain old arrayrefs being sorted.

```
my $heap = Heap::Simple->new( order     => \&byNumOrStr,
                              elements  => [Array => 0],
                             );

sub byNumOrStr
{
    my ( $val1, $val2 ) = @_;

    my $result = 
        $val1->[0] <=> $val2->[0]  # the 0th element is a number
                    ||
        $val1->[1] cmp $val2->[1]; # the 1st element is a string

    # The docs say "this should return a true value if $key1 is smaller than $key2 and a false value otherwise."
    return $result == -1;
}
```

PS. As discussed in [Secondary Order in Heap::Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146484/secondary-order-in-heapsimple/3146526#3146526), the comparison function in Heap::Simple does not want a return value of -1, 0, or 1, but rather true or false.  You need to convert the comparison result before returning from the function.

Comment: Yes my data is a list of two elements, or rather, a reference to that list.

Comment: Also why is it that you don't need to specify a return 0?

Comment: @syker: the docs say "This should return a true value if $key1 is smaller than $key2 and a false value otherwise." -- the return value of a function is the last expression evaluated, which is the comparison to -1. I can make that a little more clear in the code, which I'll do now.