# Using Any type element and key_insert to optimize insertion and secondary sort in Heap::Simple

Tags: perl, heap

Before, I had defined my elements entry as just Array in `Heap::Simple` because I did not need a secondary sort.

After implementing a secondary sort and a function for defining the elements to insert array references into a heap I made, the runtime of my insertions increased (alot!). This is covered in the documentation for `Heap::Simple` under [`Any`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Heap::Simple#Any)

However I have a hard time understanding the drawbacks of using the `Any` element type. Will I be creating extra array references? Should I be using `key_insert` to decrease runtime?

Here is the code as it currently stands:

```
my $heap = Heap::Simple->new( order     => \&by_num_or_str,
                              elements  => [Function => \&first_two_slots]
                             );

sub by_num_or_str
{
    my ( $a, $b ) = @_;

    my $result = 
        $b->[0] <=> $a->[0]  #0-th element is a number
                ||
        $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]; #1-st element is a string

    return $result == -1;
}

sub first_two_slots 
{ 
    my $array_ref = shift; 
    return [ @$array_ref[0,1] ]; 
}
```

Context: [Inserting Array References into Perl Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151415/inserting-array-references-into-perl-heap)

Comment: As discussed in the previous two posts regarding Heap::Simple, your sort function is wrong. It needs to return true or false, but currently your function is returning -1, 0, or 1. Consider what happens when $val2 is greater than $val1, so your function returns 1, but Heap::Simple thinks that means that $val1 < $val2. It will change the element order in a way that is incorrect. It could even cause the sort algorithm to thrash internally.

Comment: You've had a few questions recently centered around `Heap::Simple`, and it might be that it isn't the best solution for your problem.  What is it that you are ultimately trying to do?

Comment: @Ether Editing original post to reflect correct and functional sort function. I've verified that the sort function does work.

@Eric Strom My problem initially stemmed from the fact that I needed to a secondary ordering/sorting on the array references I was inserting into the heap. I thought it would have been a simple matter of looking at another value in the array I was concerned with.

Comment: In the documentation, it reads "...it often makes sense to not let the heap calculate the key, but do it yourself before the insert...". Don't you use the same memory and incur the same runtime if you were to calculate the key yourself as opposed to letting the heap calculate the key?

Comment: Is the first_two_slots function creating a new array reference? Is there a way to avoid creating a key every time an insertion is made into the heap when all key information is already present in the element.