# Secondary Keys with Heap::Simple in Perl

Tags: perl, insert, key, heap

I wanted to investigate if anyone has ever used a secondary key when inserting into the Heap::Simple in Perl? If so, was your performance ever impacted?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this at [Using Any type element and key_insert to optimize insertion and secondary sort in Heap::Simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161593/using-any-type-element-and-key-insert-to-optimize-insertion-and-secondary-sort-in)? Perhaps you would be better off contacting the module developers directly about your issues.